# I have changed maximum upload size to 1024M in php.in file but it doesnt taking effect in centos7

Tags: php, centos, centos7

I have changed `upload_max_filesize`,`post_max_size`,`max_execution_time`, `max_input_time`, `memory_limit` in "php.ini" file in centos located in `/etc/php.ini`. But it doesnt take any effect after rebooting Apache or even the whole server.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you say it doesn't take any effect, do you mean the changes do not show up in the php.ini on the Apache or something else? If the former, make sure you actually edited the correct php.ini. Put a phpinfo() file on your webserver and check what it gives you for the ini it used.

Comment: yes my changes doesn't shows up. although i put a phpinfo() file in webserver and its shows same php,ini file and location.

Comment: have you checked if there are other ini files in "Additional .ini files parsed" that can overwrite your settings?

Comment: There is only one php.ini located in centos server path is /etc/php.ini